# MySQL count field values before LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to get this to work, but something is tripping me up. I search here on SO but haven't found any topic describing my specific case. I have the following schema

Fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac8162/6

table `records`:

```
| ID | CONTRACT |   NAME   | STATUS  |
|----|----------|----------|---------|
|  1 | US       | FOO      | status1 |
|  2 | US       | BAR      | status1 |
|  3 | UK       | ABC Inc. | status3 |
|  4 | PL       | EFG LTD. | status2 |
|  5 | UK       | XXX Inc. | status2 |
|----|----------|----------|---------|
```

table `transactions`:

```
| ID | RECORD_ID | RESPONSE_DELAY | STATUS  |
|----|-----------|----------------|---------|
|  1 |         1 |           8889 | status1 |
|  2 |         1 |           8813 | status1 |
|  3 |         1 |           5908 | status2 |
|  4 |         1 |           4779 | status3 |
|  5 |         2 |            519 | status1 |
|  6 |         2 |           8804 | status1 |
|  7 |         3 |           2604 | status1 |
|  8 |         3 |           5054 | status2 |
|  9 |         3 |            385 | status3 |
| 10 |         4 |           8852 | status1 |
| 11 |         4 |           4330 | status1 |
| 12 |         4 |           4507 | status1 |
| 13 |         4 |           6282 | status2 |
| 14 |         4 |           5789 | status3 |
| 15 |         4 |           8685 | status4 |
| 16 |         5 |           8339 | status1 |
| 17 |         5 |           9543 | status1 |
| 18 |         1 |           7870 | status1 |
|----|-----------|----------------|---------|
```

`records` has one to many relationship to `transactions`.
I am trying to get a report out of it grouped by contract. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 

t0.`contract` as contract,

COUNT(DISTINCT t0.`id`) as rec_num,
COUNT(t1.`id`) as tr_num,

AVG(t1.`response_delay`) as rd_avg,

SUM(CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s1,
SUM(CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s2,
SUM(CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s3

FROM 
records as t0

LEFT JOIN transactions AS t1 
ON
(t0.id = t1.record_id)

GROUP BY contract ORDER BY t0.`id` DESC
```

result:

```
| CONTRACT | REC_NUM | TR_NUM |  RD_AVG   | S1 | S2 | S3 |
|----------|---------|--------|-----------|----|----|----|
| PL       |       1 |      6 | 6407.5    |  0 |  6 |  0 |
| UK       |       2 |      5 | 5185      |  0 |  2 |  3 |
| US       |       2 |      7 | 6511.7143 |  7 |  0 |  0 |
|----------|---------|--------|-----------|----|----|----|
```

I am aiming to get count of each status type per contract, counting only record status and not transaction status, the result I am after:

```
| CONTRACT | REC_NUM | TR_NUM |  RD_AVG   | S1 | S2 | S3 |
|----------|---------|--------|-----------|----|----|----|
| PL       |       1 |      6 | 6407.5    |  0 |  1 |  0 |
| UK       |       2 |      5 | 5185      |  0 |  1 |  1 |
| US       |       2 |      7 | 6511.7143 |  2 |  0 |  0 |
|----------|---------|--------|-----------|----|----|----|
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 

t0.`contract` as contract,

COUNT(DISTINCT t0.`id`) as rec_num,
COUNT(t1.`id`) as tr_num,

AVG(t1.`response_delay`) as rd_avg,

count(distinct CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status1' THEN t0.id  END) as s1,
count(distinct CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status2' THEN t0.id  END) as s2,
count(distinct CASE WHEN t0.`status`='status3' THEN t0.id  END) as s3


FROM 
records as t0

LEFT JOIN transactions AS t1 
ON
(t0.id = t1.record_id)


GROUP BY contract ORDER BY t0.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should probably select from transactions and join records. This way it'd be faster due to primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result you're looking for (thought it could probably be tidied up further):

```
SELECT a.`contract`
   , a.`rec_num`
   , b.`tr_num`
   , b.`rd_avg`
   , a.`s1`
   , a.`s2`
   , a.`s3`
FROM
   (SELECT `contract`
     , COUNT(`id`) AS rec_num
     , SUM(CASE WHEN `status`='status1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN `status`='status2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s2
     , SUM(CASE WHEN `status`='status3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s3
   FROM records
   GROUP BY
    contract ORDER BY `id` ASC) AS a
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT t0.`contract` AS contract
     , COUNT(t1.`id`) AS tr_num
     , AVG(t1.`response_delay`) AS rd_avg
    FROM
       records AS t0 
    LEFT JOIN
       transactions AS t1 ON (t0.id = t1.record_id)
    GROUP BY t0.`contract`) AS b
ON
   a.`contract`=b.`contract`
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, it does give the result I am after, but I am not too keen on using several sub-queries

Comment: Cool no worries - I didn't think of using count distinct but that is definitely the better way to go in this case. Worth bearing in mind though that in certain cases when working with tables at different grains (with different primary keys) you'll have to pre-aggregate before being able to get the result you're looking for - either by doing so in a sub-query (if the tables are small enough), or by aggregating into temp tables first.